# ASP.NET MVC: Is it possible to send error data to a non-POST page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

Since POST request is separate, I have to do all the stuff I already did in a GET request again. So is it possible to redirect to the same page, but as a GET request?

I know it's kinda confusing...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(...) {
    ...
    return View("Foo", modelWithErrorsData); // Returns POST, I need GET
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`RedirectToAction()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx)?

```
return RedirectToAction("Err", model);
```